# In Memory QFile with fwrite

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, qpixmap, qbytearray

Rather than going to the filesystem to save and read back a PGM image file, I want to do this in memory. Can I somehow use a QBuffer as an in memory QFile to bypass saving to the filesystem:

```
            QFile filename(QString("/home/pi/frame-%1.pgm").arg(i));
            bool didOpen = filename.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
            qDebug() << "Did open file: " << didOpen << filename.fileName();
            int fileHandle = filename.handle();
            FILE * f = fdopen(dup(fileHandle), "wb");
            int res = fprintf(f, "P5 %d %d 65535\n", w, h);
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                    uint16_t v = img[y*w+x];
                    //v = htobe16(v);
                    res = fwrite((uint8_t*)&v, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, f);
                }
            }
            fclose(f);

            QPixmap pixmap;
            bool didLoad = pixmap.load(QString("/home/pi/frame-%1.pgm").arg(i));
            emit updateScreen(pixmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes.

You already have most of your data ready. We just need to turn it into a format that QPixmap can read directly. For that we use the `QPixmap(const char *const[] xpm)` constructor to make a pixmap from memory. By happy coincidence this constructor takes an array of pointers, not a straight array, which saves having to copy the bitmap data!

Untested code:

```
char *lines[] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * h + 1); // 1 extra for the header
char header[100]; 
sprintf(header, "P5 %d %d 65535\n", w, h);
lines[0] = header;
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
   lines[y + 1] = (char *)&img[y * w]; // note y+1 offset
}

QPixmap pixmap(lines);
emit updateScreen(pixmap);
free(lines);
```

Note: `sizeof(char *)` returns the size of a char *pointer*, so in the first line we allocate an array of pointers of `h` lines + 1 for the header. After setting the first "line" of the array to the header we copy the address offsets of your `img` memory block in the remaining "lines" and feed it to QPixmap. After that we're done.